# Proving a group is a normal subgroup from its order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups such that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $o(G)=120$ and $o(H)=24$, and there exists a in $G-H$ such that $aH=Ha$.
Prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

I've been stuck on this for days now. have tried Lagrange theorem, indexes, and many other methods with no luck. please help.

Comment: As @runway44 points out, the hypothesis $aH=Ha$  is just saying that $a \in N_G(H)$, which immediately implies that $N_G(H)=G$.  I wonder whether you would have found the problem easier if the hypothesis has been that the index of $H$ in $G$ is prime rather than being told the exact orders of$H$ and $G$. Hypotheses in problems are often designed to distract!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the normalizer $N_G(H)$. We can say that $H\subseteq N_G(H)\subseteq G$.

By Lagrange's theorem, $|H|$ divides $|N_G(H)|$ which also divides $|G|$.

Since $[G:H]=5$ is prime, there are no intermediate divisors between $|H|$ and $|G|$, so we conclude that $|N_G(H)|$ must be one of these, so $N_G(H)$ is one of $H$ or $G$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 3):

I assume $a \notin H$.

If $a^2 \in H \cup aH$ then $H \cup aH$ is a subgroup of $G$. By Lagrange theorem, this is impossible. Similarly, we see that $a^3 \notin H \cup aH \cup a^2H$ and $a^4 \notin H \cup aH \cup a^2H \cup a^3H$. Thus, we have five disjoint cosets of $H$ in $G$: $H$, $aH$, $a^2H$, $a^3H$, $a^4H$. Their union is all of $G$.

Also, $a^kH = Ha^k$ for every $k=0, 1, 2, 3, 4$. Thus, $H$ is normal.