# Actions on left and right cosets of a subgroup of prime index.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

This raised up while trying to answer [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3946614/810157).

Let $G$ be a group and $H\le G$. Let be $X:=\{aH, a\in G\}$ and $Y:=\{Ha, a\in G \}$. The maps $\circ: G\times X\to X$ and $\star:G\times Y\to Y$, defined respectively by $g\circ aH:=gaH$ and $g\star Hb:=Hbg^{-1}$, are both left transitive actions, with pointwise stabilizers $\mathrm{Stab}_\circ(aH)=aHa^{-1}$ and $\mathrm{Stab}_\star(Hb)=b^{-1}Hb$, respectively. Is there any group action-theoretic argument to conclude that, if the two orbits have prime size (*i.e.* $[G:H]=p$) and intersect in more than one point (*i.e.* $\tilde aH=H\tilde a$ for some $\tilde a\in G\setminus H$), then they coincide (*i.e.* $H\lhd G$)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with the same argument: If $aH=Ha$, then $a$ normalizes $H$, so the normalizer of $H$ is strictly larger than $H$ itself. But as the index is prime, the only larger subgroup is $G$.

Comment: Yes, indeed $p=[G:H]=[G:N_G(H)][N_G(H):H]$, with $[N_G(H):H]>1$, implies $N_G(H)=G$. But I was actually trying to prove this latter point differently, e.g. by means of some general fact about transitive actions on sets of the same prime size, with orbits doubly (at least) crossing each other.